# DCdiag log shows deleted computers

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

We run our Daily Health Checks, this always bugs me,

The command that we run `DCDIAG /a`

Everything passes except the SystemLog test we get old PC's in it ?

I looked for the computers, the object in AD no longer exists, but the DNS and DHCP entry were there, the IP is not being re-used under another computer name...So I deleted DNS and DHCP records a couple days ago and the same PC's still are coming up...driving me nuts.

can you please tell me how to clean this up (their are at least 10 PC's that show up I just edited it for this post)?

Windows Server 2012 R2 is the OS

```
Starting test: SystemLog

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000165B

        Time Generated: 11/01/2017   08:42:11

        Event String:

        The session setup from computer 'PC-74312' failed because the security database does not contain a trust account 'PC-74312$' referenced by the specified computer.  


     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x000016AD

        Time Generated: 11/01/2017   08:59:36

        Event String:

        The session setup from the computer PC-74312 failed to authenticate. The following error occurred: 

     ......................... PDC1 failed test SystemLog
```

Comment: Are you sure your reverse lookup zone has been cleared out also? The name shown may be an old PTR record when the offending machine is actually different. Either a machine is causing this error that has an IP address of one of those old machines, or those machines still exist on your network. Regardless, you definitely have machines on your network not properly connected to the domain.

Comment: Hey @Appleoddity it doesn't appear to be that... I will keep looking around to find out